# Update statement in Django ORM

Tags: sql, django, orm, django-orm

How to implement sql statement

```
update table1 
set field1 = field2
```

using Django ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you have a mode `Table1` with the two fields, you can do this with:

```
Table1.objects.update(field1=F('field2'))
```

We here use a [**`F-expression`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) such that we reference to the *field*, not the value `'field2'`. The statement with `F(..)` would result in setting all columns to the string `'field2'` (given of course that is even possible, since `field1` has to be able to store text data).

With `Table1.objects` we obtain access to the queryset of `Table1` with (if not further specified) *all* objects. Note that we do *not* load these in memory. It is used to construct a query.

With [**`.update(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) we can then update data in the rows that correspond to the queryset (here *all* rows, but we could have filtered as well).

Like said before, we can not simply pass `'field2'` as a value. Since the ORM interprets this to setting `field1` of all rows to the *string* `'field2'`. We use an `F`-expression to reference to the column.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update) with [`F expression`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import F
Table1.objects.update(field1=F('field2'))
```